# A word for performing an act due to motivation from a prior event?

Tags: meaning, phrases

a word for performing an act due to motivation from a prior act? for example, moving in together because you have just married

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence?

Comment: **consequence, sequitur**

Answer (score 1):

**Sequitur** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sequitur)

> the conclusion of an inference
>   *"a reasonable sequitur from that announcement is that you'll be leaving the company"*